# Tuple std::get() Not Working for Variable-Defined Constant

Tags: c++, constants, type-conversion

I have been having the following problem:

```
std::tuple<Ts...> some_tuple = std::tuple<Ts...>();
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
  const int j = i;
  std::get<j>(temp_row) = some_value;
}
```

Does not compile: (in xcode) it says  " no matching function call for 'get' ".

However, the following works fine:

```
std::tuple<Ts...> some_tuple = std::tuple<Ts...>();
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
  const int j = 1;
  std::get<j>(temp_row) = some_value;
}
```

Does it have something to do with defining the value of a constant to be the value of a variable?

Thanks!

EDIT: The difference is in the `const int j = i;` vs. `const int j = 1;`

Comment: I'm not seeing a difference between the first and second code blocks.

Comment: @NathanOliver Only difference in line 3: `const int j = i` vs `const int j = 1`. Had to use a diffchecker for that..

Comment: @SamShen Oh wow.  That is a tricky one to spot.  Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I'll add a note of that!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is C++ has two different kinds of constants.  There are compile time constants and there are run time constants.  A compile time constant is a constant that is know at compile time and is the only valid constant that can be used in a template or as an array size.  A run time constant is a value that cannot change but the value is something that is not known until run time.  These constants cannot be used as a value for a template or an array size.  So in

```
std::tuple<Ts...> some_tuple = std::tuple<Ts...>();
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
  const int j = i;
  std::get<j>(temp_row) = some_value;
}
```

`i` is a run time value which makes `j` a run time constant and you cannot instantiate a template with it.  However in

```
std::tuple<Ts...> some_tuple = std::tuple<Ts...>();
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
  const int j = 1;
  std::get<j>(temp_row) = some_value;
}
```

`const int j = 1;` is a compile time constant and can be used to instantiate the template as its value is known at compile time.

Comment: Thanks Nathan, I never knew this!